# images not showing up in apple watch simulator when upgrading to xcode 7

Tags: xcode, watchkit, apple-watch

I recently upgraded to xcode 7. I noticed that when I run the apple watch simulator, none of my images are showing up.

When I look at the storyboard, all of the images are present. They are also 
there within the Images.xcassets folder.

Why would they show up in the storyboard file but not in the actual apple watch simulator? Did I need to do something when I upgraded to xcode 7?

Target membership is correctly checked for the Watchkit app storyboard and image assets folder

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you specified in your `Images.xcasssets` [Target Membership](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3Z0A.jpg) option Watch Extension and Watch App at the same time. Watch App membership is necessary to get access to your resources from a storyboard whereas Watch Extension to get access programmatically from an extension.

Comment: @prawn - Is my answer acceptable to you? Maybe you need some additional information?

Comment: Yes I have verified this. the Watchkit app has the appropriate permission in the target membership section. the images still do not display